# Jupyter Lab Extension installation warning (ipywidgets)

Tags: node.js, miniconda, jupyter-lab, ipywidgets

> warning css-loader > cssnano > autoprefixer > browserslist@1.7.7:
>   Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in
>   other tools.
>   .. SNIP...
>    warning "@jupyterlab/vdom-extension >
>   @nteract/transform-vdom@1.1.1" has incorrect peer dependency
>   "react@^15.6.1".
>    .. SNIP...
>   warning Your current version of Yarn is out of date. The latest version is "1.12.3", while you're on "1.9.4".1

Installed Jupyter Lab extension as per the official docs.

[jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_install.html#installing-the-jupyterlab-extension)

Should I worry about these ? (for working with Jupyter Lab) and I don't even have Yarn installed. I use Minoconda and using conda-forge channel

**NOTE:** Nodejs is installed in the *primary* environment while these warning came when I was installing Jupyter Lab Extensions in an environment named *geospatial*, and *geospatial* does not have Nodejs. Both don't have Yarn.

Answer (score 0):

I think it had something to with the version of **npm** which was pulling some unstable version of **yarn**. There has been few problems with  **npm** registry recently:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Npm_(software)#Notable_breakages

I waited for few months and today I removed the entire Minoconda installation. Purged all the cache and config directories and files in my $HOME too.

Then purged all files and directories related to **npm** and **nodejs** in my $HOME. Removed them from my Arch Linux. Updated Arch and then installed **nodejs** and **npm** .

last, did a fresh installation of Miniconda then installed **ipywidgets** and everything worked fine.